# Finding closest time with matching multiple columns (SQL)

Tags: sql, database

I have two tables: table 1 is the accesses to a building at a certain time, date, name

```
Accesses

    |  Date      |    Time      | Name | accesses|
    -----------------------------------------------
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:10:34.00 |  JA  |     1   | 
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:14:10.10 |  AA  |     1   |
    | 2018-10-10 |  12:15:00.45 |  BE  |     1   |
    | 2018-10-10 |  15:00:00.50 |  JA  |     1   |
    | 2018-10-10 |  16:56:56.15 |  BE  |     1   |
```

And table2 shows if there was a failures during a certain accesses

```
Failure

    |  Date      |    Time      | Name | failure |
    -----------------------------------------------
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:10:40.00 |  JA  |     1   | 
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:15:06.00 |  AA  |     1   |
    | 2018-10-10 |  16:57:01.14 |  BE  |     1   |
```

Desired output

```
   Output

    |  Date      |    Time      | Name | accesses|  Failure |
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:10:34.00 |  JA  |     1   |    1     |
    | 2018-10-10 |  10:14:10.10 |  AA  |     1   |    1     |
    | 2018-10-10 |  12:15:00.45 |  BE  |     1   |   NULL   |  
    | 2018-10-10 |  15:00:00.50 |  JA  |     1   |   NULL   |
    | 2018-10-10 |  16:56:56.15 |  BE  |     1   |    1     |
```

Basically the output will contain the accesses and matching the failure table with the closest time detected from the accesses table. I tried different algorithms of matching time stamps but I still get errors since not all the accesses have failed, which is why I want it with NULL in the output. Thank you

Comment: You definition of "closest" being loose cannot help you in find a solution. But why not just run a UNION query adding a dummy failure column for first table and ordering by date,time and name can help you?

Comment: mysql <> sql-server and please define closest

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag only with the database you are really using.

Comment: @jean the closest definition would be within a minute if the date and the name matches, union wouldn't work because I want to show NULL for the accesses that did not fail

Comment: @scsimon The closest would be within a minute

Comment: @AshA Is that I'm speaking about, you definition fails at midnight =) Also a user can fail, give up and go back hours later

Comment: good point on the midnight @jean

Comment: @jean that's a good point =) but the times are only from 8:00 to 17:00

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Databases differ in how time is represented.  But, the general idea is that you can approach this using `exists`:

```
select a.*,
       (case when exists (select 1
                          from failures f
                          where f.name = a.name and
                                f.date = a.date and
                                f.time > a.time - interval '1' minute and
                                f.time < a.time + interval '1' minute 
             then 1 else 0
        end) as failure_flag
from accesses a;
```

This uses a flag with the values `0` and `1`.  Obviously you can remove the `else 0` clause to get `NULL` instead of `0`.

This would actually work more accurately if the date and time were combined.  It may not be worth adding the fix for midnight, depending on the nature of your data.

Comment: thank you! What would your approach be if there are some records where the time could be as close as 10 seconds or higher than 1 minute?

Comment: @AshA . . . You just need to adjust the time inequalities.

Answer (score 1):

From the comments, it seems like this join condition would work

```
select distinct
    a.*
    ,Failure = case when f.Name is not null then 1 else null end
from Accesses a
left join Failure F on 
    f.Name = a.Name 
    and f.Time > dateadd(minute,-1, a.Time)
    and f.Time < dateadd(minute, 1, a.Time)
    and f.Date = a.Date
```

Here's a way, handeling midnight by making a `DATETIME` out of your seperate columns. Notice i added an extra row to each table.

```
declare @Accesses table (Date date, Time time, Name char(2), accesses bit)
insert into @Accesses
values
('2018-10-10','10:10:34.00','JA',1 ),
('2018-10-10','10:14:10.10','AA',1),
('2018-10-10','12:15:00.45','BE',1),
('2018-10-10','15:00:00.50','JA',1),
('2018-10-10','16:56:56.15','BE',1),
('2018-10-10','23:59:56.15','XX',1)

declare @Failure table (Date date, Time time, Name char(2), failure bit)
insert into @Failure
values
('2018-10-10','10:10:40.00','JA',1), 
('2018-10-10','10:15:06.00','AA',1),
('2018-10-10','16:57:01.14','BE',1),
('2018-10-11','00:00:01.15','XX',1)



select distinct
    a.*
    ,Failure = case when f.Name is not null then 1 else null end
from @Accesses a
left join @Failure F on 
    f.Name = a.Name 
    and cast(convert(varchar,f.date) + ' ' + left(convert(varchar,f.time),8) as datetime) > dateadd(minute,-1,cast(convert(varchar,a.date) + ' ' + left(convert(varchar,a.time),8) as datetime))
    and cast(convert(varchar,f.date) + ' ' + left(convert(varchar,f.time),8) as datetime) < dateadd(minute,1,cast(convert(varchar,a.date) + ' ' + left(convert(varchar,a.time),8) as datetime))
```

Comment: This could duplicate rows if there is more than one failure within a minute of an access.

Comment: thank you! What would your approach be if there are some records where the time could be as close as 10 seconds or higher than 1 minute?

Comment: No, not higher than a minute because you said it has to be within a minute

Comment: You can change the -1 and 1 in the dateadd functions to what ever "range" you want though